# nested loops not working, cant exit inner loop

Tags: excel, nested-loops, vba

i trying use a defined range to loop through an auto filter to copy the data then loop through an array of ranges where i want to paste value the data.

im running into issues as the inner loop continues to execute and all ranges have the same values.

thinking i somehow need to condense this to 1 loop but for the life of me can not figure out how get both to increment together in the same loop?

```
Sub TrendTables()

Dim rng As Range, dailyTrendrng As Long, c As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim aTrendRng(1 To 16) As Range

Set aTrendRng(1) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A2")
Set aTrendRng(2) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K2")
Set aTrendRng(3) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A29")
Set aTrendRng(4) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K29")
Set aTrendRng(5) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A56")
Set aTrendRng(6) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K56")
Set aTrendRng(7) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A83")
Set aTrendRng(8) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K83")
Set aTrendRng(9) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A110")
Set aTrendRng(10) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K110")
Set aTrendRng(11) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A137")
Set aTrendRng(12) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K137")
Set aTrendRng(13) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A164")
Set aTrendRng(14) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K164")
Set aTrendRng(15) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A191")
Set aTrendRng(16) = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("K191")


'clear ranges on Daily Trends tab
Set rng = Sheets("Daily Trends").Range("A2:S24, A29:S51, A56:S78, A83:S105, A110:S132, A137:S159, A164:S186, A191:S213")
rng.ClearContents

'turn off any previous filters
If Sheets("daily dump").AutoFilterMode Then
    Sheets("daily dump").AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
End If


With Sheets("daily dump")
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set c = Sheets("mapping").Range("BG1:BG16")

For Each c In Sheets("mapping").Range("BG1:BG16")

Sheets("daily dump").Range("A4:P" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & c.Value
Sheets("daily dump").Range("A4:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    For dailyTrendrng = LBound(aTrendRng) To UBound(aTrendRng)
        aTrendRng(dailyTrendrng).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Next


''''''this is where i want to go back to my first "FOR LOOP"


Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are going to copy Ranges (at least one row high and 16 columns (A-P) wide to single cell? Because this is how it looks like. Or you want to paste values according to the order, so for example result from cell A in filtered range to `aTrendRng(1)`, from cell B to `aTrendRng(2)` etc.? And you can remove the line `Set c = Sheets("mapping").Range("BG1:BG16")` as c is used as instance of the range in for each loop.

Comment: looking to paste values in order according the ranges defined by the aTrendRng array.

Comment: i want to paste values according to the order defined by the aTrendRng array. aka run out loop to filter range, copy filtered range, run inner loop to determine where to paste values, repeat outer iteration 1x, repeat inner loop interation 1x, etc.

Comment: Your comment line (`''''''this is where i want to go back to my first "FOR LOOP"`) is **in** your first `For` loop.

Comment: As @Rufus said, you are copying 16 columns by at least one row to your destination cells.  So the second time through your loop (with the destination's top-left corner being `K2`) you will be writing over about half of the information you wrote in the first iteration (when the top left-corner was `A2`).  Are you really wanting to copy 16 columns each time?  It seems suspicious that you have 16 destination cells (albeit that is just a "corner"), 16 criteria, and 16 columns.  So perhaps provide a screen shot of what your data looks like and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: removing the set c statement had no impact postive or negative. data is not being over written as i have columns hidden on the sheet  where im filtering the data. not sure how to provide a screenshot, essentially im summarizing my source table by business and date down to ~10columns, copying it to a new wksht where i have 2 businesses side by side (sorta like 2x8 type matrix). im doing this as i eventually need to put this into a powerpoint presentation. my problem is once all of the data has been copied each box on the destination tab contains the same data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that your copied ranges will always fit within a 27 row x 10 column destination area, the following code has been refactored to just use a single loop:

```
Sub TrendTables()

    Dim rng As Range, dailyTrendrng As Long, c As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim mappingRow As Long
    Dim aTrendRng As Variant

    aTrendRng = Array("A2", "K2", _
                      "A29", "K29", _
                      "A56", "K56", _
                      "A83", "K83", _
                      "A110", "K110", _
                      "A137", "K137", _
                      "A164", "K164", _
                      "A191", "K191")

    'clear ranges on Daily Trends tab
    Set rng = Worksheets("Daily Trends").Range("A2:S24, A29:S51, A56:S78, A83:S105, A110:S132, A137:S159, A164:S186, A191:S213")
    rng.ClearContents

    With Worksheets("daily dump")
        'turn off any previous filters
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
        End If

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        mappingRow = 1
        For dailyTrendrng = LBound(aTrendRng) To UBound(aTrendRng)
            'This line could be used if we wanted to get rid of "mappingRow", but
            'it's a bit harder to understand
            '.Range("A4:P" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & Worksheets("mapping").Range("BG" & (dailyTrendrng - LBound(aTrendRng) + 1)).Value
            'so we will use the following line instead
            .Range("A4:P" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & Worksheets("mapping").Range("BG" & mappingRow).Value
            .Range("A4:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Worksheets("Daily Trends").Range(aTrendRng(dailyTrendrng)).PasteSpecial xlValues

            mappingRow = mappingRow + 1
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Major changes were:

- I created an extra variable (`mappingRow`) to point to each cell in the "mapping" sheet.  (I included a commented out line which would achieve the same thing without the extra variable, but using the extra variable is probably easier to understand.)  This is the only change that was **really** necessary to achieve what you wanted.
- I just stored the 16 destination range addresses, rather than 16 different range objects.  It just seemed like it would be a bit easier to maintain this way.
- I changed `Rows.Count` to `.Rows.Count` so that it referred to the "daily_dump" sheet and not to the active sheet.
- I used `Worksheets` rather than `Sheets` everywhere - the `Sheets` collection includes `Chart` sheets, so it is usually better practice to refer specifically to `Worksheets` when you **know** that you are using a `Worksheet`, and only use `Sheets` when you are unsure whether it is a `Worksheet` or `Chart` that you are referencing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help this is working beautifully. This definitely gives me something to review and learn what you were doing and why. Thank you very much for that. i actually when with the option that you commented out as the mapping counter was not incrementing. I thank you sooo much for  your help and offering this alternative!!!

Comment: @geoTheNeo - Oops - I forgot to include the `mappingRow = mappingRow + 1` line into the code - I have now edited the answer